# Mosfet decreasing Vgs

Tags: mosfet, voltage-divider

i want to know whether it is possible that a positive source voltage begins to develop if say too high a voltage is dropped across the voltage divider 600k ohm and 10Mohms.

For example, removing the 5V power supply from the voltage divider and attaching instead a higher voltage supply of say 10V. Most of the voltage will be dropped across R4, but is it possible that a voltage develops in the opposite direction to R3 and therefore reducing Vgs?

Question taken from:
[Why do most N Channel MOSFET Circuits have the Source Pin tied to ground? + Circuit Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/120668/why-do-most-n-channel-mosfet-circuits-have-the-source-pin-tied-to-ground-circ)

Referring to answer 1:
R2 will prevent that from happening because the higher Vgs goes, the higher the current through R2 goes, which will cause the voltage dropped across it to increase, raising the voltage on the source, partially defeating the rise in Vgs

[image: schematic]

Comment: I can't follow what you're asking here. You're talking about a MOSFET, but your circuit shows a BJT, and all voltages here are positive under all conditions.

Comment: I think OP is asking about the Ids-Vgs relationship and if it is two-way. But if you lock Vgs it can't change so Vds must change via Ids.

Comment: Apparently if you increase the voltage dropped across the voltage divider, Vgs can decrease due to voltage increase at the source

Comment: You don't realize how unclear all your language is. What you described in your comment is not what you described in your post. There are also two resistors in the divider across which voltage can drop and the entire divider itself. In your opening post it is also unclear when you are talking about R3.

Comment: What is unclear about it?

Comment: Its very simple, when you increase the voltage dropped across the voltage divider, does the voltage at the source increase [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Well I'll say this: you fixed Vgs so it doesn't change. You also literally directly connected the source pin to +5V so that definitely won't change (assuming a MOSFET and not the BJT you have actually drawn.)

Comment: Read the post then come back. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/120668/why-do-most-n-channel-mosfet-circuits-have-the-source-pin-tied-to-ground-circ [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: I think you're the one who doesn't know the terms they are using. Look up the symbols and terminal names for MOSFET, BJT, NPN, PNP, PMOS, and NMOS and make sure they are what you think they are.

Comment: That link you posted makes sense, but your question doesn't.

Comment: If you don't think your source pin is directly connected to +5V then there is nothing to talk about here since it doesn't get simpler than that.

Comment: Remove the power source from the divider. And what you can see is the resistance of the first resistor varies, its between 50k and 600k ohms. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: How does the voltage across the voltage divider affect the increase in Vgs from initial to steady state? The problem cannot be synthesized simpler than this. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Malemna - Hi, This is your one and only warning. Please stop being rude / unkind in your comments. You have broken the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) several times in recent comments, so they have been deleted / edited by moderators. Please read that page and ensure that you comply from now onwards. Thanks.

Comment: Now that the image has been changed to show a MOSFET, it no longer uses the references from the question (R3, R4).  It also no longer includes a voltage divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your words say. Is this really what you are asking?

Because it is clear here that the voltage at the source pin (S) is fixed to 5V, and that the voltage at the gate (G) is fixed to some other voltage. Nothing about the source-drain current is going  to affect Vgs here since the voltage at both ends is fixed.

That's why I don't think this is what you really mean to ask since you keep asking about the source pin voltage rising but the source voltage is fixed to begin with so won't change anyways.

And even if you mistook the drain terminal for the source terminal,  it still doesn't make sense because I presume in your mind that the rise in voltage at the drain, is due to increased current. But changing the divider voltage from 5V to 10V increases Vg and since Vs stays the same, causes the PMOS to conduct *less* than before which decreases source-drain current.

The lower Vg is below Vs, the more the PMOS will conduct (opposite of NMOS).

Maybe this is really is your question but there are multiple mistakes which make me think it's not your question.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9ab4.png]

Comment: INcrease voltage from initial to steady state

Comment: PLease refer to the post diagram, all incorrect in your answer unfortunately!

Comment: @Malemna In the new schematic of yours, increasing Vg increases Vgs since Vs stays the same 0V at the start when off. Since it is an NMOS the highger Vg is above Vs the more it conducts. So it will conduct. R2 current flows causing Vs to rise. Since Vg now stays the same, Vgs decreases and the MOSFET turn off more. Negative feeback so it finds an equilibrium. This is called a source follower. Output voltage (drain voltage) is about Vg plus some mostly constant MOSFET gate-source threshold voltage.

Comment: You can do the same thing in PMOS but you need to reverse everything properly and the output voltage  follows relative to +V rather than ground.

Comment: yes perfect, thank you